# Cookie sent in cross-site context will be blocked in future Chrome versions asp.net core 7 mvc

Tags: cookie, asp.net-core-mvc, site

на сайте (asp.net core 7 mvc) постоянно вылетает предупреждение "Cookie sent in cross-site context will be blocked in future Chrome versions". В прпедупреждении говорится, что куки, отмеченные SameSite=none и secure будут заблокированы для межсетевых запросов в следующих версиях браузера. Скорее всего это связано с тем, что на сайте присутствует iframe, и в самой документации написано:

> Приложения, которые используются, могут столкнуться с проблемами или с cookie sameSite=Lax sameSite=Strict, так как  рассматривается как межсайтовые сценарии.

Почитав еще информацию в интернете, если я правильно понял, то для межсетевых запросов необходимо установить SameSite=none и secure

> SameSite=None must be used to allow cross-site cookie use.(документация)

Но это же противоречит самой ошибке, где говорится, что с данными атрибутами будут заблокированы межсетевые запросы... Как быть?
Сами куки с samesite=none, как видно на скрине ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин самой ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить эту проблему, чтобы всё заработало? Если необходимо, могу приложить больше информации